# Formula Field base on 2 picklist fields and 2 checkboxes

Tags: formula-field

I am  creating a text formula field with the following conditions -

I have tried -

```
IF( 
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Status , "Not Touched"), 
        ISPICKVAL(Lead_Source__c , "Event")
    ), 
    OR(
        (Telemarketing_Followup__c, "1"),
        (Inside_Sales_Follow_up__c , "1")
    ), 
    "Pre0qualification", 
)
```

And I'm getting the error `syntax missing ')'`. Also I am not sure if this condition is correct

I couldn't be succeed in creating this as I am facing some difficulties. It would be great if someone can help me here :(

Comment: Hi @Arya Daphne, Welcome to SFSE Community!!. Could you please help to edit your question and add what you have tried and where you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You should [edit] your question to include the attempt you've made at your formula, and include any error messages (word-for-word, don't try to paraphrase) and/or describe the output that you're getting.

Comment: Hi @MohanRaj I have tried - IF(
   AND(ISPICKVAL(Status , "Not Touched"), ISPICKVAL(Lead_Source__c , "Event")), 
      OR((Telemarketing_Followup__c, "1"),( Inside_Sales_Follow_up__c , "1")), "Prequalification",
  )  And I'm getting the error syntax missing ')'. Also I am not sure if this condition is correct.

Comment: Superb!! Please add the above tried formula into your question and update the error/not satisfied scenrio on your question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, As per your comment you're missing `IF` loops `criteria` checking portion. your formula should be in follows,

```
IF (

(AND(ISPICKVAL(Status , "Not Touched"), ISPICKVAL(Lead_Source__c , "Event")) && OR(Telemarketing_Followup__c = TRUE, Inside_Sales_Follow_up__c = TRUE)), ////Criteria checking

"Prequalification", //// Execute when Criteria satisfied Condition

"Error/Some String" ///// Execute when Criteria not satisfied Condition

)
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works :)

Comment: @AryaDaphne, Please help to choose this as best answer if it's correctly fit for your question which is help to new users in forward days whom having the same doubt.